# How to use Javascript plugin in in ionic 3 (Typescript)?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I found a plugin API to communicate with the social network Vkontakte.
[link vkapi plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vkapi)
How do I install it in my project?
The compiler swears at

```
var VK = require('vksdk');
```

I am using the latest versions of ionic.

Comment: ..you cant. Its a node package and meant to be used server side not client side

Answer (score 0):

That is nodejs syntax for including a node package. We dont use plugins in ionic like that. To use plugin in ionic firstly you add plugin by running command : "Ionic cordova plugin add plugin-name". And then include it in your providers in app.module.ts file.